# keep getting error trying to add records into table

Tags: mysql

mysql>

```
insert  into `customers` 
( `customerNumber`,
`customerName`,
`contactLastName`,
`contactFirstName`,
`phone`,
`addressLine1`,
`addressLine2`,
`city`,
`state`,
`postalCode`,
`country`,
`salesRepEmployeeNumber`,
`creditLimit`) 
values 
(497, 
'SomeName', 
'LastNameSample', 
'800-555-1234', 
'123 Main St', 
'Apt 41', 
'Some Town', 
'CA', 
'96024', 
1002, 
20000);
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

above is what I have written in order to add a record into a Customer table but I keep getting an error. help me, please?

Comment: Error is very clear (13 columns to be inserted but only 11 supplied..).

Comment: I edited and remove legit looking information.  Seeing things broken down, now you can see what field(s) were missing.